# Applescript: if file contains any of names move to specific folder

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to make a script that will do this:

There will be a .txt file with a list of names, one per paragraph, like this:

```
name1
name2
name3
name4
name5
```

There also will be a folder with lots of files in it.
I want the script to look at every file in that folder, and in any of the names listed in .txt file are contained in the file name, then move that file to a specific folder. If the file name does not contain one of the names from the list, then move that file to a different folder.

Example:

```
- There are "name1", "name2" and "name3" in the .txt file.
- There are "000name2000.jpg", "000name7000.jpg" and "000name3000.jpg" in the folder. 
- "000name2000.jpg" contains "name2" in it so it should be moved to folder1.
- "000name3000.jpg" should be moved to folder1 as well. 
- And "000name7000.jpg" should be moved to folder2.
```

I want it to be so because this list with names will be very long and I want script to be as small as possible.

This is how my script looks like now:

```
property source_folder : alias "path:to:source_folder"
property tattoos_folder : alias "path:to:first_folder"
property models_folder : alias "path:to:second_folder"
property text_file : alias "path:to:text_file.txt"

process_folder(source_folder)

on process_folder(this_folder)
  set these_items to list folder this_folder without invisibles
  set container_name to name of (info for this_folder)
  repeat with i from 1 to the count of these_items
  set this_item to alias ((this_folder as Unicode text) & (item i of these_items))
  if folder of (info for this_item) is true then
  process_folder(this_item)
  else
  process_item(this_item, container_name, i)
  end if
  end repeat
end process_folder

on process_item(this_item, c, i)
  if i < 10 then
  set i to "000" & i
  else if (i < 100) and (i > 9) then
  set i to "00" & i
  else if (i < 1000) and (i > 99) then
  set i to "0" & i
  end if

  set r to (random number from 0 to 9999)
  if r < 10 then
  set r to "000" & r
  else if (r < 100) and (r > 9) then
  set r to "00" & r
  else if (r < 1000) and (r > 99) then
  set r to "0" & r
  end if

  tell application "System Events"
  -- get file extension so not overwritten
  set e to name extension of this_item
  set new_name to "" & r & "" & c & "" & i & "." & e
  set name of this_item to new_name
  move this_item to first_folder      -- THIS IS WHERE THIS NEW PART OF CODE SHOULD BE
  end if                              -- IF NAME IS (meets name from .txt file) THEN MOVE TO first_folder,
  end tell                            -- IF ANOTHER THEN MOVE TO second_folder
end process_item

display notification "All images were processed." with title "New" sound name "Glass.aiff"
tell me to quit
```

Comment: Please describe more in detail the relationship between the name and the folder. Why is name3… moved to folder 1 and name7… moved to folder2 ? And where are the destination folders located? What are the real names of the folders? Do they exist or are they supposed to be created?

Comment: It doesn't really matter. It's just .txt with Instagram nicknames in it. Files that contain such names in it should be moved to one folder and all other files should be moved to another. Folders don't matter, too. And yes, they are already created.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes you can define your text file and folder paths in the script. You can add choose dialogs if you need to.
This script puts all files in the source folder into a list, then it goes through each file, checking if a name in the name list matches, and if it does, moves it to folder1, otherwise, if it is still left after checking all the names, then moves it to folder2.

```
-- define folder/file locations
property nameFile : ((path to desktop) & "nameList.txt") as string
property sourceFolder : ((path to desktop) & "test:") as string
property folder1 : ((path to desktop) & "folder1:") as string
property folder2 : ((path to desktop) & "folder2:") as string

try
    set move1List to {}
    set move2List to {}
    set nameList to paragraphs of (read file nameFile)

    set fileList to list folder sourceFolder without invisibles

    repeat with n from 1 to count (fileList)
        set thisFile to item n of fileList
        -- set fileName to name of (info for alias (sourceFolder & thisFile))
        set fileRef to alias (sourceFolder & thisFile)
        repeat with thisName in nameList
            if (thisName as string) is in thisFile then
                set end of move1List to fileRef
                exit repeat
            end if
        end repeat
        if exists fileRef then set end of move2List to fileRef
    end repeat

    display dialog "About to move: " & return & (count move1List) & " files to folder1" & return & (count move2List) & " files to folder2"
    -- move all the files in the lists
    tell application "Finder" -- can try "System Events"
        move move1List to folder folder1
        move move2List to folder folder2
    end tell
    -- could avoid Finder by iterating to a shell script using 
    -- do shell script "mv " & quoted form of thisFile & space & quoted form of folder1

on error err
    display dialog err
end try
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to make it with "System Events"? There will be more than 30,000 images to process.

Comment: No, System Events can't move files. You could try to build two lists of files to move and then use Finder at the end, but the real time cost here is the cost of copying the files. If performance is a problem, you could build it in a do shell script. (See as example: https://discussions.apple.com/message/11964571#11964571 ). But, if this is a one-time job, can't you just let it run for a bit and do its work?

Comment: Nope, I am using this script pretty often. This is kind of part of my work.

Comment: I edited the script so that it isolates the Finder call which does all the copying all at once. This really will minimize the copy time. You could also instead do a shell command mv to see if that speeds it up.

Comment: It's just moving all the folders from source to one of folders. And by the way I just checked my other script and "System Events" sure can move files.

Comment: Is there a way to write this script for "System Events" and I will just check if it will work or not. Because the script that I am using now it uses "System Events" for moving files.

Comment: System Events has long had a 'move' command, but its broken/buggy. If it works for you, then that'd be great. I just tested my script changing the move block to tell app "System Events" instead of "Finder", and it properly moved half of the files.